# Jquery Slick don´t show number of slides i need

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I use slick for show reponsive sliders in this case carousel with images inside divs , the problem it´s not show the number i want show of sliders , show all and rotate yes , but for example if i put show "5" show more and if i change this numner always show the same , i think it´s because i use divs inside cotnent and not images , etc , i try add slide with the calss of div , but continue don´t works fine

**Divs structure**

```
    <div id="web_rotador" class="web_car">
    <div id="web_carrousel_product_content">1</div>
<div id="web_carrousel_product_content">1</div>
<div id="web_carrousel_product_content">1</div>
<div id="web_carrousel_product_content">1</div>
<div id="web_carrousel_product_content">1</div>
    </div>
```

**Arrows**
    
    .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before 
    { 
    color:red !important;
    }

**My Script**

```
jQuery('#web_rotador').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  //infinite: true,
  slide: '.web_car',
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  //slidesToScroll: 3,
  //centerMode:true,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  adaptiveWidht: false,
  //dots: true,
  arrows: true,


});
</script>
```

I need in this case works showing the numer slides i put for show - 5 - , when load , regards and thank´s for the help

Answer (score 0):

You are saying to your carousel that uses the class `.web_car` as slider and there is no element with that class, just removes that line and should be work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $('.web_car').slick({
      autoplay: true,
      //slide: '.web_car', //remove this line
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: 5,
      adaptiveHeight: false,
      adaptiveWidht: false,
      //dots: true,
      arrows: true,
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>


<div id="web_rotador" class="web_car">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```